# Editing in jtable's customize option

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable, tablecelleditor

After changing some of code in jtable using the 'customize code' option in netbeans the main method araises an erron like "illegal expression".

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Accept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Accept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Accept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Accept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Accept().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

what's occured here?

Comment: can you show us what have you changed and the stack trace of your error?

Comment: i added pieace of code for one click editing on cell.

Comment: code of that      for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    defaultEditor = (javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor) jTable1.getDefaultEditor(jTable1.getColumnClass(i));
    defaultEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);

Comment: error is denoted in public static void main(String args[]) {}  showing red line under the main method(as an illegal exprssn).

Comment: bt if i takeout that piece of code there is no error,if the code exists under the constructor it will run perfectly.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First create you own Cell Editor

```
public class MyCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{

    public MyCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    @Override
    public void setClickCountToStart(int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setClickCountToStart(1);
    }   
}
```

Then assign MyCellEditor to your table, just like:

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new MyCellEditor());
```

Hope that help.